# Inline css using google fonts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I subscribe to a website that only allows limited customization by account holder. I was told by the site  admin that if I wanted to change the look of the font I would have to use a script tag with inline CSS. I am new to coding and have been trying to use Google fonts. Can any one help show me some code examples on how I can pull googles fonts into an inline CSS to change the fonts on one page.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Goto [Google Fonts Site](https://www.google.com/fonts)

Goto Font you want to Use.

For Example I am using Revalia https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:

There you will get Code put that code in a Website

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Revalia' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And then you can use that particular font using Inline CSS as below:

```
<style>
   body {font-family: 'Revalia', cursive;}
</style>
```